# Using when/unless without saving the result of a Monadic action

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to write this without the variable `x`?

```
foo = do
  x <- checker bar
  when x dostuff
```

I'm imagining something similar to LambdaCase:

```
foo' = do
  checker bar >>= \case
    True -> dostuff
    _    -> return ()
```

but without the second case pattern, obviously.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most straightforward answer is to desugar the `do` by hand, and then see if you can write some code that's equivalent but prettier. Your `do` desugars to:

```
checker bar >>= \x -> when x dostuff
```

So, the answer will have to look like `checker bar >>= f`, where `f` is equivalent to

```
\x -> when x dostuff
```

Well, that's a lot like partially applying `when`, right? Except you want to supply the second argument instead of the first, so you need to `flip` it:

```
checker bar >>= flip when dostuff
```

Answer (score 15):

In `Control.Monad.Extra`, check out `whenM`. For your example, that would be:

```
foo = whenM (checker bar) doStuff
```

Here's a longer example, just to show you how to multiple statements in your `whenM` structure.

```
foo = do
  doStuff1
  doStuff2
  whenM (checker bar) $ do
    doStuff3
    doStuff4
    doStuff5
  doStuff6
```